# Starting page number getting in .aux file

Tags: auxiliary-files, lastpage

How to get starting pagenumber getting in .aux file?
we have option to get lastpage number using "lastpage.sty" to print in .log file,
we need same way to get first page number via .aux file?

Please find MWE file is as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
sample
\clearpage
sample
\clearpage
sample 
\end{document}
```

Aux file output:

```
\relax
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{3}}
\xdef\lastpage@lastpage{3}
\gdef\lastpage@lastpageHy{}
```

Comment: The start page number is 1. Why do you need the aux for this?

Comment: We export value of starting page number from aux file to another application

Comment: Well add \labe{firstpage} to the begin of your document